# Finding a Virgin Internet Password

Tags: passwords, internet, wireless-networking, modem

So I'm at a friends house and they have an internet connection.
He does not have a wireless router, instead he connects his laptop directly to the internet using an ethernet lead and modem.

I enabled ICS on the laptop to allow my iPad to connect to wireless, however I cannot find the password.

It is not on the modem, and as it is a wired connection is has never been required to connect to the internet on the laptop.

Does anyone have any idea how I could solve this problem? (maybe even reset the password?)

It's the first time I have used ICS.

I am using Windows 7, and I have checked everything I can find in windows network settings but cant find anything related to an ICS password, neither can I find anything on google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Are you sure that your iPad is not asking for a *wireless* password? As in, one that was set up on the laptop for ICS connections?**

If you're using Internet Connection Sharing, it's fairly unlikely that the Internet connection itself is asking for a password, as ICS is just going to share whatever connection is already available on the laptop, which you seem to indicate is connecting fine, no password required.

I would walk you through checking to see if a password is configured for ICS on the laptop, but you don't mention what OS it is running (Windows, OS X, etc.). But if you managed to set up ICS, you should be able to find how to disable any password requirement that may have been established.